# Openvswitch: multiple virtual bridges over one bonding interface

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, redhat-enterprise-linux, qemu, centos-6.6

My ultimate goal is to configure a RedHat 6.6 server with Openvswitch as shown in the following image:

[image: Several Virtual Bridge over bonding interface]

Interfaces configuratión files are:

ifcfg-eth0

```
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=none
```

ifcfg-eth1

```
DEVICE=eth1
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=none
```

ifcfg-bond0

```
DEVICE=bond0
BONDING_OPS="mode=4 miimon=500"
DELAY=0
DEVICETYPE=ovs
TYPE=OVSBond
OVS_BRIDGE=virbr0 
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
NM_CONTROLLED=no
HOTPLUG=no
OVS_OPTIONS="bond_mode=balance-tcp lacp=active"
BOND_IFACES="eth0 eth1"
```

ifcg-virbr0

```
DEVICE=virbr0
DEVICETYPE=ovs
TYPE=OVSBridge
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
NM_CONTROLLED=no
DELAY=0
HOTPLUG=no
```

I don't know how associate multiple virtual bridge to one bonding interface. When I define bonding interface can only specify a virtual bridge. I need define a virtual bridge for each group of virtual machines.

If this is not possible, that strategy can go on to isolate traffic from each group of virtual machines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround is use patch port to connect multiple virtual bridges:

ifcfg-virbr0

```
DEVICE=virbr0
DEVICETYPE=ovs    
TYPE=OVSBridge
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
NM_CONTROLLED=no
DELAY=0
HOTPLUG=no
```

ifcfg-virbr1

```
DEVICE=virbr1
DEVICETYPE=ovs
TYPE=OVSBridge
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
NM_CONTROLLED=no
DELAY=0
HOTPLUG=no
```

ifcfg-patch1-0

```
DEVICE=patch1-0
ONBOOT=yes
DEVICETYPE=ovs
TYPE=OVSPatchPort
OVS_BRIDGE=virbr1
OVS_PATCH_PEER=patch0-1
```

ifcfg-patch0-1

```
DEVICE=patch0-1
ONBOOT=yes
DEVICETYPE=ovs
TYPE=OVSPatchPort
OVS_BRIDGE=virbr0
OVS_PATCH_PEER=patch1-0
```

[image]

Maximun patch port is 5

```
ovs-vsctl show
Bridge "virbr0"
    Port "virbr0"
        Interface "virbr0"
            type: internal
    Port "patch0-1"
        Interface "patch0-1"
            type: patch
            options: {peer="patch1-0"}
Bridge "virbr1"
    Port "bond0"
        Interface "eth0"
        Interface "eth1"
    Port "patch1-0"
        Interface "patch1-0"
            type: patch
            options: {peer="patch0-1"}
    Port "virbr1"
        Interface "virbr1"
            type: internal
```